# Make the border even around Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, border, navbar

This is my first post, although I've been benefitting from Stack Overflow for quite some time.

I just created a [site](http://blog.taniarascia.com/) for practice, but I'm having an issue with the borders around the navbar.

Here's the convoluted code I'm using:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav > li > a:first-child {

    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav > li > a:last-child {

    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    font-size: .8em;
}}
```

The aim is to have a 2px border all the way around.

Unfortunately, this is leading to some issues -

- The middle borders are 3px
- The first child left border is 1px. (this is apparent if you click the "about" link and the focus is moved.

Answer (score 2):

***CSS***

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav > li:first-child > a {

    border-left: 2px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav > li:last-child > a {

    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
.navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    border: 0px solid #fff;
    font-size: .8em;
}}
```

> What you are trying is right but the element which you are applying `:first-child` and `:last-child` are wrong you should apply for `li` not for `a` Try the above CSS.